# How to delete records using ActiveRecord with mySQL function as WHERE condition

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table named ChatSessions where I keep track of active users in the chatroom. I need to prune expired user sessions from the table every 10 minutes. Using pure php-mysql is plain simple but I'm totally clueless how to convert this into ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter. The plain SQL query is below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ChatSessions`
WHERE `SessionExpires` < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )
```

Can anybody tell me what is the equivalent code in CodeIgniter using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should do it:

```
// You can use custom strings in the where() function
$where = "SessionExpires < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )";
// although you may need to set the third parameter to FALSE in order to stop CI from protecting your fields.
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
$this->db->delete('ChatSessions');
```

You could also try the following (but I don't know if this will work):

```
$where_condition = "DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )";
$this->db->where("SessionExpires <", $where_condition, false);
$this->db->delete('ChatSessions');
```

Comment: I don't think ActiveRecord allows functions on WHERE conditions, the same reason why we need to use set($field,$value) for Select()

Comment: The user guide gives this example: $this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);

Answer (score 2):

Converting it to ActiveRecord if you already have the SQL seems like a waste of time.  I'd just execute the SQL directly.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ChatSessions 
        WHERE SessionExpires < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, that crossed my mind but I was trying to steer away from "direct" queries in order to retain some kind of consistency on my code. I still haven't figured out yet how to do with ActiveRecord though.